# How to call class function in python

Tags: python

```
class TwoCard:
  def __init__(self, card1, card2):
     self.card1 = card1
     self.card2 = card2
```

How do I call card1 or 2

Comment: Your question is unclear. And I suspect that `card1` and  `card2` are not callable. But if they _are_ callable, that's a rather odd class design you have there.

Answer (score 2):

```
class TwoCard:
  def __init__(self, card1, card2):
     self.card1 = card1
     self.card2 = card2

def f():
    print('f called')
def g():
    print('g called')

two = TwoCard(f, g)

two.card1()    # call card1
two.card2()    # call card2
```

Output:

```
f called
g called
```